# Why does gsutil rsync on CoreOS fail with 'CommandException: arg () does not name a directory, bucket, or bucket subdir'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, coreos, gsutil

On a recent Google Cloud Platform CoreOS VM, the command `gsutil rsync -r gs://some-bucket-here dest` fails with:

`CommandException: arg (dest) does not name a directory, bucket, or bucket subdir.`

```
$ gsutil --version
gsutil version: 4.28
```

The result is the same whether source or destination is local, ie copying to or from a bucket:

```
$ mkdir test
$ ls -al test
total 16
drwxr-xr-x. 2 user user 4096 Nov 29 05:53 .
drwxr-x---. 6 user user 4096 Nov 29 05:53 ..
$ gsutil -m rsync -r gs://some-bucket-here test
CommandException: arg (test) does not name a directory, bucket, or bucket subdir.
```

```
$ touch test/blah
$ ls -al test
total 20
drwxr-xr-x. 2 user user 4096 Nov 29 05:54 .
drwxr-x---. 6 user user 4096 Nov 29 05:53 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user    0 Nov 29 05:54 blah
$ gsutil -m rsync -r test gs://some-bucket-here
CommandException: arg (test) does not name a directory, bucket, or bucket subdir.
```

Is this something to do with the way CoreOS handles the root file system?

---

Additional data:
`gsutil cp -r gs://some-bucket-here test` at least pretends to copy the files, iterating over bucket contents, but nothing is written to disk.

Comment: I am able to replicate this behavior on CoreOS. I checked on Debian 9 GCE VM it worked fine on the Debian image. As it seems a possible issue, you can report it on google cloud [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187243)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have done so: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70062485